# ms graph add email to distribution list

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, distribution-list

I'm trying to manage a distribution list in ms 365 from my website where I keep all user info. I'd like the users to be added to a distribution list with their personal email and so without being a member of the ms365 environment.

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph
->setBaseUrl("https://graph.microsoft.com/")
->setApiVersion("beta")
->setAccessToken($this->accessToken);
$group_id = 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx';
$data = json_encode(array(
    "GivenName" => "John",
    "Surname" => "Doe",
    "EmailAddresses" => array(
        array(
            "Address" => "email@example.com",
            "Name" => "John Doe"
        )
    )
));
        
$response = $graph->createRequest("post", "/groups/{$group_id}/members")
->addHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "application/json"))
->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
->attachBody($data)
->setTimeout("1000")
->execute();
```

The response I get is:

> Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/members` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Unsupported resource type 'DirectoryObject' for operation 'Create'.","i (truncated...)

Further error stack:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(69): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL, Array, NULL) #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(204): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(153): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL) #3 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(48): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() #4 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(248): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run(true) #5 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(224): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn() #6 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(269): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() #7 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(226): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList() #8 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending() #9 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait() #10 
C:\xampp\htdocs\site\content\libraries\MicrosoftGraph\vendor\microsoft\microsoft-graph\src\Http\GraphRequest.php(270): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('post', 'beta/groups/aa2...', Array)
```

Now, from the documentation I understand the proper way to add one to a list/group is by using:

> "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryObjects/{id}"

with its user ID but I'd like to use a non-existing user. From within the portal I can do this as admin but is there a way for the graph API to fix this as well?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Can you try to get a longer stack trace ? What is under the `(truncated ...)` ? The doc mention that a 400 is issued when the object is already part of the group, but it does not seem to be the case here. I guess your best shot is to have a 2-step process: first create the user, then assign it to the group.

Comment: as per request @homer i added more of the error. Your solution would indeed work but that kind of ignors the issue at hand because the thing is, I do not want the email address to become a true member. In the distribution list itself it is possible to have non-ms-users. So why not from the API?

Comment: thank you for the details, sadly this stack trace won't help. I guess you really need the full API response, maybe you could try to do the call using Postman in order to get the full output. Or you could temporarily capture it to display it on screen or log it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I never used this api, though, the documentations does not say that {id} should refer to an existing user, it says:

> In the request body, supply a JSON representation of the id of the
> **directoryObject, user, or group** object you want to add.

So I'm guessing if you post to the directory object it should work

Comment: would you have a link to this section?

Comment: I would but I'm from mobile now and the in-app browser is not allowing me to copy the URL on chrome. Is the same link you posted, just scroll down a few blocks till you reach the request part. Did it work?

Comment: @Mart here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#response

Comment: Hmm, would you mind adding a code example of how to solve this issue? Because I'm not quite sure on how to interpret your answer